# What are the extensible solutions for one-way sync in .NET?

Tags: .net, synchronization

I've a project where in addition to user-entered data I'll have external data sources:

1. SQL Server
2. Web Services

In both cases I do not have to track changes, getting all data and then just merging it is ok. The external data can't be edited within the application (only referenced), so merging here means just duplication prevention.

As a developer I want to be able to define transformation rules so that they are extensible, testable and can reuse business rules/logic. As an admin, I need an ability to define the sync schedule and easily see sync log/status.

Is there an existing solution that takes care of all that?

Comment: What do you mean by "merging"? If you don't track changes, how do you know if a difference is due to a local change, a remote change, or both?

Comment: There are no local changes possible for this data, so merging is just about preventing duplicates. Thanks, updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the Sync Framework can probably do this, but honestly if you're just pulling data from a service (or a database), stripping out data that's duplicated locally and then merging it together it won't be hard to do. You will probably find it more work to figure out how to tell a framework or library to do what you want then you would to just do it yourself.

That'd be even more true if you build a simple web service for the SQL Server data, because then your updater only needs to know how to talk to services and you just give it a list of services. The actual update process is pretty easy (get stuff from the service, write it to disk, then merge it in with the local client's data to use it).

Comment: It is not technically hard to the sync itself, but I am not really fond of building the required infrastructure. For example, previously I solved scheduling by using console app + windows task scheduler, but that always felt like a hack to me. But that's a fair answer anyway, if no one else adds anything, I will accept it.